# Wrapping Oauth2 response

Tags: spring, spring-security

How to modify oauth2 response:

existing:

```
{    
  "access_token": "25313d2c-3d24-429c-ab42-39f712aa7d8f",    
  "token_type": "bearer",    
  "refresh_token": "da9d14c5-32aa-44c1-8c64-83244b85e150",    
  "expires_in": 27843637    
}
```

requirement :

```
{    
  "success":true,    
  "access_token": "25313d2c-3d24-429c-ab42-39f712aa7d8f",    
  "token_type": "bearer",    
  "refresh_token": "da9d14c5-32aa-44c1-8c64-83244b85e150",    
  "expires_in": 27843637    
}
```

same while any authentication problem comes:
existing:

```
{    
  "error": "invalid_grant",    
  "error_description": "Bad User Credentials."    
}
```

requirement:

```
{    
  "success":false,    
  "error": "invalid_grant",    
  "error_description": "Bad User Credentials."    
}
```

or I may customize json fully.

please help me I tried in so many ways but not working.

Comment: Can you not modify it on the client side? It seems 'success' is always true when 'access_token' exists and false when 'error' exists.

Comment: yes i can do that, but other side i want to customize json fully like i can change key name, etc.....